# Windows Phone TextBox with a button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, textbox

I'm creating an application for windows phone 8 and I need a search box.

On theory, I want this :

[image]

Where the user writes what he wants to search.

Though I want to have a button at the end (represented by the X) that when the user click it, it deletes all text. Also this button should only appear when there is text or it is different from the default text.

The actual problem if what I have (the picture) is that when I focus the textbox, the button disapears.

How can I do it? Seen several websites, but cant make what I want.

EDIT : XAML

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Text="find" />
<Button Content="X" Width="40" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" />
```

Comment: Please post your existing XAML and code.

Comment: Why not just put the button on the outside of the text box, scale it to a square the same vertical size and collapse it. Then add an event handler for TextChanged that checks the contents of the box when someone changes the text. If it is not default and not empty then set the button to visible?

Comment: Added XAML @PeterTorr . It works redwizard, but i wanted to put it inside for design purposes.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me. The color of your button isn't the default white is it? I noticed in your XAML you don't have a color set. The text box changes from a light grey to the same color as the button default when you tap on it.

Comment: Color was the problem, got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work with Textbox `GotFocus` event and `LostFocus` event. It looks like Google search box. It will surely help you.
First of all download image for the button from [here](http://www.i2symbol.com/images/symbols/frames/box_drawings_light_diagonal_cross_u2573_icon_256x256.png)

**XAML:**

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,531">
            <TextBox Name="txtSearch" 
                     Text="Search"
                     GotFocus="txtSearch_GotFocus"
                     LostFocus="txtSearch_LostFocus"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     Foreground="Gray"/>

              <Button 
                    Click="Button_Click"
                    Width="50" 
                    Height="60" 
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Margin="10" Grid.Row="0">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform"  ImageSource="/box_drawings_light_diagonal_cross_u2573_icon_256x256.png" />
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
           </Grid>
```

**XAML.CS:**

```
private void txtSearch_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtSearch.Text == "Search")
        {
            txtSearch.Text = "";
            SolidColorBrush Brush1 = new SolidColorBrush();
            Brush1.Color = Colors.Black;
            txtSearch.Foreground = Brush1;
        }
    }

    private void txtSearch_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtSearch.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            txtSearch.Text = "Search";
            SolidColorBrush Brush2 = new SolidColorBrush();
            Brush2.Color = Colors.Gray;
            txtSearch.Foreground = Brush2;
        }

    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtSearch.Text = "Search";
    }
```

Comment: Was having problems using an image in a button, and this answer was the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default the text box will turn white when you tap on it. It is the same color as your "X" button. Change the color of the button to something else.

Add Foreground="Black" to your XAML for your button or pick a color from the color picker.